# Erro de repente no sistema de login

Tags: php

Eu estava fazendo um sistema de login e estava funcionando tudo perfeitamente de repente eis que aparece este erro abaixo:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as
>   array in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PC\gentelella-master\production\Controllers\valida.php:24
>   Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PC\gentelella-master\production\Controllers\valida.php
>   on line 24

**valida.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();    
    //Incluindo a conexão com banco de dados
    require_once("config.php"); 

    $conn = new Conexao();
    //O campo usuário e senha preenchido entra no if para validar
    if((isset($_POST['user'])) && (isset($_POST['senha']))){
        $usuario = $_POST['user'];
        $senha = $_POST['senha'];

        //Buscar na tabela usuario o usuário que corresponde com os dados digitado no formulário
        $resultado = $conn->select("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE BINARY nome = '$usuario' and BINARY senha = '$senha' LIMIT 1");

        if (count($resultado) <= 0) {
            $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuário e/ou senha Inválidos";
            header("Location: ../Views/logincs.php");
        }

        $res = $resultado[0];
        //Encontrado um usuario na tabela usuário com os mesmos dados digitado no formulário
        if(isset($resultado)) {
            $_SESSION['usuarioId'] = $res['id'];
            $_SESSION['usuarioNome'] = $res['nome'];
            $_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] = $res['nivel'];
            $_SESSION['senha'] = $res['senha'];
            $_SESSION['OK'] = true;
            if($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == 1 or $_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == 2){
                header("Location: ../Views/index.php");
            } else if ($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == 3 or $_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == 4){
                header("Location: ../Views/index.php");
            }
            //Não foi encontrado um usuario na tabela usuário com os mesmos dados digitado no formulário
            //redireciona o usuario para a página de login
        }
        //O campo usuário e senha não preenchido entra no else e redireciona o usuário para a página de login
    }
?>
```

Comment: Atente-se à linha 24... ela que possui o erro.

Comment: Sim amigo, só não sei qual seria esse erro

Answer (score 1):

Verifique com var_dump se $res é um array ou um objeto. Se for um objeto, altere as declarações como `$res['nome'];` para `$res->nome`;

Comment: resolvi aqui era isso mesmo obrigado Lima